# Ratio Distribution - The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent or failed to converge after 100 iterations

Tags: scipy, simulation, normal-distribution, integral, scipy.stats

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm, rv_continuous
from scipy.special import erf
import scipy.integrate as integrate

class normal_ratio_wiki(rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, z, mu_x, mu_y, sigma_x, sigma_y):
    
        a_z = np.sqrt(((1/(sigma_x**2))*(np.power(z,2))) + (1/(sigma_y**2)))
        b_z = ((mu_x/(sigma_x**2)) * z) + (mu_y/sigma_y**2)
        c = ((mu_x**2)/(sigma_x**2)) + ((mu_y**2)/(sigma_y**2))
        d_z = np.exp(((b_z**2)-((c*a_z**2))) / (2*(a_z**2)))
        pdf_z = ((b_z * d_z) / (a_z**3)) * (1/(np.sqrt(2*math.pi)*sigma_x*sigma_y)) * \
        (norm.cdf(b_z/a_z) - norm.cdf(-b_z/a_z)) + ((1/((a_z**2) * math.pi * sigma_x * sigma_y))*np.exp(-c/2))

        return pdf_z

    def _cdf(self, z, mu_x, mu_y, sigma_x, sigma_y):
        cdf_z = integrate.quad(self._pdf, -np.inf, np.inf, args=(mu_x, mu_y, sigma_x, sigma_y))[0]
        
        return cdf_z

rng1 = np.random.default_rng(99)
rng2 = np.random.default_rng(88)

# Sample Data 1
x = rng1.normal(141739.951, 1.223808e+06, 1000)
y = rng2.normal(333.91, 64.494571, 1000)

# Sample Data 2
# x = rng1.normal(500, 20, 1000)
# y = rng2.normal(400, 10, 1000)

z = x / y

# 1st approach with normal_ratio_wiki 
mu_x = x.mean()
mu_y = y.mean()
sigma_x = x.std()
sigma_y = y.std()

rng3 = np.random.default_rng(11)
nr_wiki_inst = normal_ratio_wiki(name='normal_ratio_wiki', seed=rng3)
nr_wiki_vars = nr_wiki_inst.rvs(mu_x, mu_y, sigma_x, sigma_y, size = 100)
nr_wiki_params = nr_wiki_vars.fit(nr_wiki_vars)
```

Hello, I am working on simulating the ratio distribution of two uncorrelated normal distributions by defining the custom distribution using `scipy`.

Approach is from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Uncorrelated_noncentral_normal_ratio).

While calling `scipy.dist.rvs` or `fit` method from custom defined distribution above using either approach, I get the following errors `RuntimeError: Failed to converge after 100 iterations.` and `IntegrationWarning: The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent.` respectively. If we comment `_cdf(...)`, then the process takes a lot of time to run `scipy.dist.rvs` but then fails on calling `fit`. Tried different bounded intervals but no success.

I believe implementing custom `_rvs`, `_ppf` and/ or `_fit` methods may help resolving the issue. How should we define this based on above `_pdf` and `_cdf` methods? Please advise.

Note that example `integrate.quad(nr_wiki_inst.pdf, -np.inf, np.inf, args=(mu_x, mu_y, sigma_x, sigma_y))` works separately without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

The `_cdf` method is essentially the same as the generic implementation, so the rest assumes that it's removed. I'm also assuming the `_pdf` implementation is correct, and I haven't seen anything that suggests otherwise yet. It reduces to the Cauchy distribution when the `mu`s are 0 and the `sigma`s are 1, it seems to integrate to 1 even when the parameters change, and the PDF appears to agree with random variates (see below).

Integrating the PDF to get the CDF is bound to be pretty slow with `quad`, but one thing that will make it much faster is to replace the use of `scipy.stats.norm.cdf` with `scipy.special.ndtr` in the PDF. SciPy distributions have a lot of overhead, but the special function jumps straight to evaluating the CDF of the normal distribution.

```py
from scipy import stats, special
x = 1.5
%timeit special.ndtr(x)
# 1.43 µs ± 726 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
%timeit stats.norm.cdf(x)
# 107 µs ± 21.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

This speeds up the CDF of your distribution by a factor of 10x-20x.

Improving the speed of RVS is also very easy. The generic implementation of `_rvs` inverts the CDF (numerically) to get the PPF, and it passes in a uniformly distributed random number to get each observation (inverse transform sampling). We override `_rvs` to just generate two normal random variates and take the ratio.

```py
    def _rvs(self, mu_x, mu_y, sigma_x, sigma_y, size=None, random_state=None):
      x = random_state.normal(mu_x, sigma_x, size)
      y = random_state.normal(mu_y, sigma_y, size)
      return x/y
```

To check the agreement between this RVS implementation and the PDF:

```py
rng = np.random.default_rng(8235834852452842)
nr_wiki_inst = normal_ratio_wiki(name='normal_ratio_wiki', seed=rng)

mu_x = 1
mu_y = 2
sigma_x = 3
sigma_y = 4
dist = nr_wiki_inst(mu_x, mu_y, sigma_x, sigma_y)

rvs = dist.rvs(size = 100_000)
plt.hist(rvs, density=True, bins=np.linspace(-10, 10, 300))

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 300)
pdf = dist.pdf(x)
plt.plot(x, pdf)
```

[image]

This generated 100_000 random variates from the distribution (in 8ms) and allows us to visually compare the histogram against the PDF. The agreement is good, and the apparent excess of the histogram can be explained by the fact that the histogram is normalized over the range [-10, 10] instead of the entire real line.

You can get a fast (but approximate) PPF method using [`scipy.stats.sampling.NumericalInversePolynomial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.sampling.NumericalInversePolynomial.html#scipy.stats.sampling.NumericalInversePolynomial). It's easier to describe what `NumericalInverseHermite` does: evaluate the CDF at many points and use that data to interpolate the PPF. `NumericalInversePolynomial` also works using interpolation, but is more advanced, and it only needs the PDF.

```py
dist2 = sampling.NumericalInversePolynomial(dist, center=0, random_state=rng)
# show that `dist2`'s `ppf` method is the inverse of the original `cdf`
dist2.ppf(dist.cdf(1.5))  # 1.5000000001244032
```

I think `fit` is having trouble in part because it doesn't know that `sigma_x` and `sigma_y` must be positive.  For that, you need to define `_argcheck`:

```py
    def _argcheck(self, mu_x, mu_y, sigma_x, sigma_y,):
        return (sigma_x > 0.) & (sigma_y > 0.)
```

But there are other issues, and I don't think I'll debug it right now. Instead, we can define `_shape_info` so that we can use the [`scipy.stats.fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fit.html) function with this distribution instead of the `fit` method of the distribution.

```py
# _ShapeInfo is private/not documented
# so don't use this for production code
from scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure import _ShapeInfo
...
    def _shape_info(self):
        # parameter name, discrete (True or False), domain, domain includes endpoints
        return [_ShapeInfo("mu_x", False, (-np.inf, np.inf), (False, False)),
                _ShapeInfo("mu_y", False, (-np.inf, np.inf), (False, False)),
                _ShapeInfo("sigma_x", False, (0, np.inf), (False, False)),
                _ShapeInfo("sigma_y", False, (0, np.inf), (False, False))]
```

Now the `fit` function can be used:

```py
# generate random variates to fit
rvs = dist.rvs(size=200)

# assign rough bounds to parameters
bounds = dict(mu_x=(-10, 10), mu_y=(-10, 10), sigma_x=(1e-1, 10), sigma_y=(1e-1, 10))
res = stats.fit(nr_wiki_inst, rvs, bounds=bounds)

# Show that negative log likelihood of fitted parameters is better
print(res.nllf((1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1)))  # 454.43887891645863
print(res.nllf())  # 453.19908132025944
# The latter corresponds with the fitted parameters.
# It's lower, so it's a better fit according to MLE
```

All together:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate, stats, special
from scipy.stats import sampling
from scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure import _ShapeInfo

class normal_ratio_wiki(stats.rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, z, mu_x, mu_y, sigma_x, sigma_y):
    
        a_z = np.sqrt(((1/(sigma_x**2))*(np.power(z,2))) + (1/(sigma_y**2)))
        b_z = ((mu_x/(sigma_x**2)) * z) + (mu_y/sigma_y**2)
        c = ((mu_x**2)/(sigma_x**2)) + ((mu_y**2)/(sigma_y**2))
        d_z = np.exp(((b_z**2)-((c*a_z**2))) / (2*(a_z**2)))
        pdf_z = ((b_z * d_z) / (a_z**3)) * (1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma_x*sigma_y)) * \
        (special.ndtr(b_z/a_z) - special.ndtr(-b_z/a_z)) + ((1/((a_z**2) * np.pi * sigma_x * sigma_y))*np.exp(-c/2))

        return pdf_z
        
    def _rvs(self, mu_x, mu_y, sigma_x, sigma_y, size=None, random_state=None):
        x = random_state.normal(mu_x, sigma_x, size)
        y = random_state.normal(mu_y, sigma_y, size)
        return x/y
    
    def _argcheck(self, mu_x, mu_y, sigma_x, sigma_y):
        return (sigma_x > 0) & (sigma_y > 0)

    def _shape_info(self):
        return [_ShapeInfo("mu_x", False, (-np.inf, np.inf), (False, False)),
                _ShapeInfo("mu_y", False, (-np.inf, np.inf), (False, False)),
                _ShapeInfo("sigma_x", False, (0, np.inf), (False, False)),
                _ShapeInfo("sigma_y", False, (0, np.inf), (False, False))]

rng = np.random.default_rng(11)
nr_wiki_inst = normal_ratio_wiki(name='normal_ratio_wiki', seed=rng)

mu_x = 1
mu_y = 2
sigma_x = 3
sigma_y = 4
dist = nr_wiki_inst(mu_x, mu_y, sigma_x, sigma_y)
rvs = dist.rvs(size = 100_000, random_state=rng)
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 300)
pdf = dist.pdf(x)
plt.plot(x, pdf)
plt.hist(rvs, density=True, bins=np.linspace(-10, 10, 300))

dist2 = sampling.NumericalInversePolynomial(dist, center=0, random_state=rng)
dist2.ppf(dist.cdf(1.5))  # 1.5000000001244032

rvs = dist.rvs(size=200, random_state=rng)
bounds = dict(mu_x=(-10, 10), mu_y=(-10, 10), sigma_x=(1e-1, 10), sigma_y=(1e-1, 10))
res = stats.fit(nr_wiki_inst, rvs, bounds=bounds)
print(res.nllf((1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1)))  # 399.2571952688255
print(res.nllf())  # 396.24324681778955
```